# React - Properly triggering callback that represents a state change event from react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, callback, state

In an app I am building a custom range slider. I have a state that maintains the current value and also a prop that is exposes a callback triggered on change of this internal state. Below is how I am currently doing this:

```
const Slider = ({onChange}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0)
  // ...
  useEffect(() => onChange?.(value), [value, onChange])
  // ...
}
```

The issue here is that the `onChange` is triggered on component load since `onChange` is part of the dependency list. But if I remove this from the list, it will not trigger on changing the definition of the callback.

What is the correct approach here?

1. The above is correct and the subscriber of the `onChange` should take into account that it will be called even when change actually doesn't happen.
2. The `onChange` is triggered in the same function that sets the value state - but it can happen in multiple places and I need to ensure it is called in all the required places.

Comment: Why are you using `useEffect` and not calling `onChange` directly from the slider?

Comment: @LaurenceSummers I am writing a custom slider handling drag from both touch and mouse and so there are a lot of places from where the `value` potentially changes. This is needed since I want to support for steps, and orientations etc which are all very finicky on the html input slider.

Comment: I get you, but I think a better approach would be calling `onChange` directly, that way it only runs when intended. At the moment you’re introducing an intermediary state `value` which is unnecessary. 

Remember `onChange` can be any function passed into `Slider` it doesn’t need to rely on specific HTML events. So I would use pass the slider state as a prop along with the onChange function and call as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two key points:
The first one, OnChange() has two different meanings here: one is to feedback the change of value, and the other is to feedback the change of onChange() itself. The two should probably be kept separate.
The second point is that useEffect() is designed to perform behaviors for a parameter that has been given, and its focus is "get a new value and do something", such as querying based on a new url data. useEffect() is actually a design that tries to decouple code based on some specific concerns. If you don't use useEffect() to process business logic, you should consider the problem of repeated code for "first run". But OnChange() focuses on different things. OnChange() is inherently highly bound to setState(). As you said, OnChange() should only care about data changes, which is different from useEffect(). Therefore, a better design maybe is not to use useEffect(), but to wrap setState(), and call OnChange() in this wrapped function. Use useEffect() if you have something to do every time you get a value you care about. The function hook of "prepare to end the side effect of the last value concerned" that comes with useEffect() can handle the things to be done every time the value changes.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer, here is a slider from scratch fully functional.

```
import {useState} from "react";
const CustomSlider = ({min, max, value, onChange}) => {
    const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = useState(value);
    const handleSliderChange = (event) => {
        const newValue = parseInt(event.target.value);
        setSliderValue(newValue);
        onChange(newValue);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="range"
                min={min}
                max={max}
                value={sliderValue}
                onChange={handleSliderChange}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default function App() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0)
    return (
        <div>
            <CustomSlider
                min={0}
                max={100}
                value={value}
                onChange={val => setValue(val)}
            />
            {value}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I am writing my own Slider component - not from a UI library.

Comment: can you provide the whole code then?

Answer (score 0):

To make your implementation work as you intended you need to do 2 things:

1. Prevent unnecessary call of `onChange` callback on the first render, to do so you can check whether `Slider` is mounted or not, and call `onChange` only if `Slider` was already mounted, following changes required to the `useEffect` inside `Slider` component:

```
const Slider = ({ onChange }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0)
  // ...
  const isMounted = useRef(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted.current === false) {
      isMounted.current = true
      return
    }
    onChange?.(value)

    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false
    }
  }, [value, onChange])
  // ...
}
```

2. Make sure `onChange` callback that you pass to the `Slider` component is memoized using React's `useCallback` hook, it prevents unnecessary calls of `useEffect` inside `Slider` component where `onChange` callback in a dependecy list due to rerender of the outer component.